# Instagram Basic Display API: how to get CODE

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I have followed each and every steps from below [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started). I am able to get the results as expected.

In Step 4 Authenticate the Test User, it says to open below URL to get the CODE. When I open the URL it redirects me to login page. If I get log in then only I get the CODE from url.

**Question** is: How do I get the CODE without getting logged in? Because I just want to display some random posts of a user.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope=user_profile,user_media
  &response_type=code
```

Comment: NO you cant. It is necessary to log in to get code, because you are getting code of that specific account.

Comment: Thank you. So I can't display/integrate posts as a slider in the website without a logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is not possible. Depending on the security-setting of the user you have to be part of their community to access the posts. 
What should be possible is to have a user to login with and that implement some kind of crawler to get the requested data.